# Can't Find Saved Bundles In NetSuite

Tags: bundle, netsuite, sandbox

I'm trying to install a saved bundle from my company's NetSuite sandbox into production.

I've already made a bundle in the sandbox and made it public. But when I search for the bundle It doesn't appear.
I've tried looking up multiple articles on how to make and install bundles.
I'm able to make the bundles, but I can't find them when I search for them.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I need to find one, I follow this path:

Customization > SuiteBundler > Search & Install Bundles.  Select Advanced on the search page.
Enter any keywords that may help, or leave blank for everything.
Set the Location to Sandbox Account.
Enter your Sandbox Account Number (usually something like 123456_SB)
Leave Availability set to All.
Hit Search.

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 0):

Click on the option 'Save to repository' at the time of bundle creation and when searching the created name in any other instances, select the location and enter ID/Name.

Below link will help you to create bundle.
https://netsuiteblogs.curiousrubik.com/creating-bundle-in-netsuite

Comment: Linking to external pages is not likely seen on SO. Please sum up the content and directly paste it to here. Thank you.